# How to populate a database in Phoenix/Elixir on a server?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using edeliver. How can I insert seeds -- populate a database -- in Phoenix/Elixir **on a server**? I'm aware of a single way which is run Phoenix console. Is it how it's supposed to be?
I don't want a method which should work to your opion, but which haven't tried or tried but a long time ago.

If there's another way without involving edeliver, that's ok as well.

`mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs`  doesn't work on a server.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the file `./priv/repo/seeds.exs`.
You can write whatever you want in there and execute the script with

```
mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
```

EDIT: With edeliver, people have been reporting success with the following method https://github.com/boldpoker/edeliver/issues/116:

> So you could connect to your node using bin/your_app remote_console
>   and type something like:
>
> ```
> :code.priv_dir(:your_app) |> Path.join("repo/seeds.exs") |> Code.require_file()
> ```
>
> to run the seeds file.

And also:

> It worked, but I had to replace "Code.require_file()" with "Code.eval_file()". "require_file" would just freeze the console, no error shown !

Comment: @アレックス Can you elaborate that further? You should be able to ssh onto the server and run the same command there. `ssh name@server "cd location && mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs"`

Comment: **I don't want a method which should work to your opion, but which haven't tried or tried but a long time ago.**

Comment: @Johannes I haven't used it, but I believe edeliver does not send your code to the server. Only the release, which does not include anything in `priv/`.

Comment: That worked for me. Be sure to stop the server first and export MIX_ENV=prod. Can you post your error message?

EDIT: After reading the answer from @JustinWood, I begin to understand the problem. In this case I'll have another look.